# QGIS and GDAL installation conflict linux ubuntu / R

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04, gdal, qgis, rgdal

[Running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS]

While working with GIS on both `R` and `QGIS` environments, I realized that, in order to use some packages in `R` (`rgdal`, `sf`, `sp`, `tmap`...) I needed to install the package `GDAL` via the terminal.

However, by doing so, `QGIS` in uninstalled. Then, by using [these instructions](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu), terminal tells me that I "held broken packages". Hence, I can only install back `QGIS` using `sudo aptitude install` that has for consequences to remove some packages GDAL relies on to  function properly... and we're back to the start.

I know I give few details about the errors but is there a way to resolve this conflict, and get both packages installed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04. I think this was happening because GDAL was being upgraded from version 2.x.x to version 3.x.x when installing the R packages for spatial analysis. QGIS did not like this.

So like you I rolled back to the previous version of GDAL, which for me was `GDAL 2.2.3` and works with QGIS version 3.16.3-Hannover.

Then in R I installed an older version of `rgdal`. Since I am using `R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)` I looked up which version of rgdal came out just before my version of R and installed it using:

```
install.packages("rgdal", version="1.4-8")
```

All seems to work so far.